# Drupal 7 programatically create content type with existing fields

Tags: drupal, content-type

Problematically creating a content type with new fields and body field seems to be documented and displayed in several locations, that I have found.   How can I programmatically include a field type to a new content type using an existing field type that I created in another module?

Answer (score 0):

The code that will be created new content type we should add into `.install` file.

Lets add `hook_install()`:

```
<?php
function your_module_name_install() {
  // use get_t() to get the name of our localization function for translation
  // during install, when t() is not available.
  $t = get_t();

  // Define the node type.
  $node_example = array(
    'type' => 'node_example',
    'name' => $t('Example Node'),
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'description' => $t('This is an example node type with a few fields.'),
    'body_label' => $t('Example Description')
  );

  // Complete the node type definition by setting any defaults not explicitly
  // declared above.
  // http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_type_set_defaults/7
  $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($node_example);
  node_add_body_field($content_type);

  // Save the content type
  node_type_save($content_type);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example, but, I am not certain I understand.   I am trying to create a new content type including only one or 2 fields from an existing content type, not all fields from the existing content type or node.  If I have a content type NewCType1 with one field being NewField, and I need a content type NewCType2 that also needs NewField, will your description allow me to include NewField in content type NewCType2?